# Sending BLE messages from Laptop to Controller

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

the Controller I'm currently working with, has an integrated Bluetooth LE Interface. Now I want to send data from my Macbook, which has also a BLE Controller, to this Controller. Do you know any cool tools which suit my needs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use Apple's 'Hardware IO Tools'. It contains a tool named 'Bluetooh Explorer' which can do that.

Comment: Add some more details about your solution to the answer. :)